# Is an infinite set of disjoint subsets of the natural numbers with an infinite number of members each, countable or uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this proof valid?

I wish to prove that an infinite set of disjoint subsets of the natural numbers with an infinite number of members each, can be uncountable.

I will use a similar proof to Cantor's proof of the uncountability of the power set of the natural numbers.

We will pair our natural numbers with an infinite number of disjoint sets in a zig-zag pattern like this, so that no number appears twice.

$x\to  f(x) $

$1\to  \{4,44, 4444, 4444444,  44444444444, \dots \}$

$2\to  \{444, 44444, 44444444, 444444444444, \dots  \}$

$3\to  \{444444, 444444444, 4444444444444, \dots  \}$

$4\to  \{4444444444, 44444444444444, 4444444444444444444444444, \dots  \}$

$5\to  \{444444444444444, 44444444444444444444444444, 4444444444444 4444444444444, \dots  \}$

$\dots$

Now by Law of Excluded Middle, there are two choices for every $x \in \mathbb N$

$x \in f \left({x}\right)$

$x \notin f \left({x}\right)$

We will then form a special set $S = \left\{{x \in \mathbb N: x \notin f \left({x}\right)} \land x \notin \{ 4, 44, 444, 4444, \dots\}\right\}$

As $f$ is supposed to be a surjection, $\exists a \in \mathbb N: S = f \left({a}\right)$

Thus:

$a \in f \left({a}\right) \implies a \notin f \left({a}\right)$

$a \notin f \left({a}\right) \implies a \in f \left({a}\right)$

This is a contradiction, so the initial supposition that there is such a surjection must be false.

Comment: Why must your set $S$ be in your collection?  It seems to me that if I had a collection, $\mathscr S$ of disjoint sets we could define an injection $\mathscr S\to \mathbb N$ by taking the least element of each subset in $\mathscr S$.  (this is an injection because your sets are all disjoint).  This means that $\mathscr S$ is countable, no?

Comment: What exactly is $f$ meant to be a surjection onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Arthan has shown that your answer is incorrect; let me point out where your argument breaks down.

Remember that the diagonal argument has *two* parts:

- Given a countable set $X$, we produce an object $y$ not in $X$.
- We then argue that $y$ *should have* been in $X$.

It's this second step that fails here: there is no reason to believe that $S$ should be in the list. The list doesn't purport to consist of *all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$* - the only properties that the list needs to have is that (i) the list is a list of disjoint infinite sets of natural numbers, and (ii) the union of the sets on the list is $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

A set of pairwise disjoint non-empty subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ must be countable. To see this, let $U$ be any set of pairwise disjoint non-empty subsets of $\Bbb{N}$. Then each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ belongs to at most one $X \in U$. So the partial function that maps $n \in \Bbb{N}$ to the set $X \in U$ that contains it (if there is one) is well-defined and onto. So $U$ is the image of a partial function on $\Bbb{N}$ and must be countable.

Disclaimer: "countable" means "countably infinite or finite" in the above.

Comment: It can be uncountable if we relax the disjointness to "finite intersection" (and require all subsets to be infinite). See MAD families.. They can have size $\mathfrak{c}$ (and are popular in topology to construct spaces from).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you pls give a link or something?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: MAD stands for "maximal almost disjoint". If you google for that, you will find some references.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks